# How to use Confluence markup language with Maven 3 site Plugin?

Tags: maven-3, confluence, maven-site-plugin

I'd like to use [Confluence markup language](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF35/Confluence+Notation+Guide+Overview) to generate my site using the [Maven site plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/index.html).

As said in the [doxia documentation](http://maven.apache.org/doxia/references/index.html), it seems to be possible.

Here is my file structure (as required by [the site plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/examples/creating-content.html)) :

```
src
+- site
   +- confluence
      +- index.confluence
```

But just like that, nothing is generated. By looking at the [FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/faq.html#How_to_include_a_custom_Doxia_module_like_Twiki), I tried to include the "doxia-module-confluence" in the plugin build :

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.doxia</groupId>
                    <artifactId>doxia-module-confluence</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But it's still the same, my index page is not rendered (I've got the default one).

Does somebody know how to do ?

Comment: Take a look to [maven confluence plugin](https://github.com/bsorrentino/maven-confluence-plugin). I've built it to replace use of site plugin, in order to have a documentation site having a better fit in confluence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the file structure + the usage of that dependency (`doxia-module-confluence`) is OK.

The problem was I first generate the page without the dependency (so it didn't use my confluence file to generate the index), and then I added the dependency. But I didn't run `mvn clean` before the second `mvn site` so the index was directly used from the previously generated index.html !

Answer (score 0):

generated maven sites does not match very well with Confluence style.

If you need to update Confluence pages at each deploy or release I have to suggest a small opensource plugin I have done called [confluence-maven-plugin](https://github.com/sixro/confluence-maven-plugin).
In this way, you can use maven site for other purposes...